# I need to build the following graph in latex, can can anyone suggest a package?

Tags: graph, tree, package, latex

I'm looking to build the following graph in latex, but cannot find an example of how to produce it exactly, the main issue is with the paths through the 'x'.

```
  A
 / \
B   C
|\ /|
| x |
|/ \|
D   E
```

So far I have tried 'qtree' and 'linguistics{forest}' packages.

Answer (score 0):

For simple graphs / graphics I use `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm]
        \node[draw=black,fill=white,circle,minimum size=1.5cm] (A) {A};
        \node[draw=black,fill=white,circle,minimum size=1.5cm, below left of = A] (B) {B};
        \node[draw=black,fill=white,circle,minimum size=1.5cm, below right of = A] (C) {C};
        \node[draw=black,fill=white,circle,minimum size=1.5cm, below of = B, yshift=-3cm] (D) {D};
        \node[draw=black,fill=white,circle,minimum size=1.5cm, below of = C, yshift=-3cm] (E) {E};

        \draw (A) -- (B);
        \draw (A) -- (C);
        \draw (B) -- (D);
        \draw (B) -- (E);
        \draw (C) -- (E);
        \draw (C) -- (D) node[draw=black,fill=white,circle,minimum size=1.5cm,midway] (X) {X};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```